# How to create a specific type of image slider for my webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create an image slider on my webpage that looks similar to the screen you get when you want to see all the apps open in the background of your phone, a la below:

[image: This is what I mean.]

What I want would look very similar to that. I just want the images to be tighter together and horizontal instead of vertical.

Here is a better example:

[image]

So, as you can see I have my webpage with the title at the very top and then below that I have all of my images. This is how I want it to look but I also want these images to enlarge if the user hovers over them. When enlarged the image will stay in place and text will appear on the image which the users can read.

Here is another example:

[image]

So in the image above, the user has hovered over the image and now it is displaying information and the other images are pushed to the side. The example text is the title text, background image is just the image the user hovered over and the information text is, as the name suggest, the text that gives info.

So my main question here is how I would achieve something like this?

Comment: I think you want to achieve like this https://www.cssscript.com/demo/accordion-style-content-slider-with-css3-flex-and-transition/ Please look into this. Also look into this too https://www.cssscript.com/demo/fancy-accordion-slider-pure-css/

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!